# Show status bar in Android in PhoneGap app (ie prevent fullscreen)

Tags: android, android-layout, cordova

I have a phonegap 3.0.0 application.
My application covers the status bar (the thing with the clock, reception info, etc).  Since i'm not a full screen game, this is not desirable.

I believe it's running as a "Full Screen" app.

I've found posts here on stack to do the opposite (ie make an app go full screen) and did the inverse of what was suggested.  I'm wondering if something changed in PhoneGap or perhaps the PhoneGap CLI that I used to create the project because my app is showing fullscreen.

I tried this:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);

        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 10000);
    }
```

Which explicitly tells it to NOT be in full screen mode.... but it still shows up full screen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out.

The Splashscreen plugin must be setting it to fullscreen.
By calling the `clearFlags` method AFTER `super.loadUrl`, once the app loads the status bar shows up.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 10000);

    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: nice one, I was keep trying to set this thorough configuration, didn't realise that the it's actually the splashscreen messing with the status

Comment: Splashscreen! The hidden culprit. This really should be documented

Answer (score 39):

The native code suggested above will work, but a cleaner way would be just to make sure you **don't** have in the config.xml:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

you can also set it to "false", but its actually the default value so its not necessary. works for me.

Comment: Is that an android only preference?  Would it do something weird to an ios app?  I only edited native code as a last resort so if that works it must have been undocumented at the time i posted.

Comment: I tested it only for android.

it is documented for the "phonegap build" any way:
https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

Comment: You should test it on iOS and report here :)

Comment: For me this works for the Android version but not for the iOS version. Is there a universal solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

make this change in res/xml/config.xml on eclipse.

```
<preference
    name="fullscreen"
    value="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Hide status bar
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
// Show status bar
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

The default behavior should be NOT fullscreen, have you modified your theme in xml?

Some other code I have found, just in case:

```
private void toggleFullscreen(boolean fullscreen)
{
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
    if (fullscreen)
    {
        attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    }
    else
    {
        attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    }
    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
}
```

Comment: +1 for confirming it SHOULDN'T default to full screen.  I hadn't modified any xml file.  It's whatever phonegap cli generated for me. I realized that it must be because of the splashscreen plugin thanks to your post. See my answer.

Comment: Just to let you know: http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/