# How to hide status bar - Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I am trying to hide status bar but it is not working for me.

I tried to add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

In AndroidManifest.xml But it is not working.

I also tried to add

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

In onCreate function

But nothing is working.
I am using phonegap build.
First time when i open my application status bar goes away but after 1 sec it comes back.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

---

I fix it.
In onCreate function i add this lines

```
this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Now status bar is hidden...

Comment: Have you tried it with a normal android build?

Comment: Also take a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237939/show-status-bar-in-android-in-phonegap-app-ie-prevent-fullscreen

Comment: I tried with normal build and it works but in phonegap build it is not working...

Comment: You can't hide statusbar, unless you're running immersive mode in KitKat.

Comment: I fixed it with this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

Answer (score 0):

Oficial way: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

And you can try this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Try that. You can check here: [How to hide status bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431365/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: I tried that, not working for me. Status bar is over my app when i use that code.

Comment: What is your Android version? Did you check the official link: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Comment: And btw are you using the emulator or a real device?

Comment: I am using real device. I fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by two ways

1) Programatically :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

2) Modifying `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Comment: Why you don't want to read my post at first time. I said that this ways is not working for me. I tried them. I fixed my problem by adding

this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

This Code.

Answer (score -1):

Just turn off the battery saver mode.

Comment: This does not answer the question.